# Reformatting a text file

Tags: c++, arrays, file

I am getting large (several MB) spreadsheets in txt form with way more information than I need. It is predictable. So I want to load up my input file, put the first line into an array of `char`s, pick out the few relevant pieces into an output array, copy the output array to a separate output file, and loop through for each line in the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){

char input[5459];
char output[1321] = { 0 };//initalize all values to 0
ifstream infile8;//input file
infile8.open("input.txt");

ofstream fout("output.txt");//output file

int i;
while (infile8.getline(input, sizeof(input))){

    //cout << input[2] << " \n";
    output[0] = input[18];//transaction status
    //I select a bunch more info from the arrays here like above
    i = 0;
    while (i <= 1320){
        fout << output[i];
        i++;
    }
    fout << '\n';

    //output = { 0 };//reset output file
}

return 0;
}
```

It currently never enters the loop.

Comment: One of your problems is here :  infile8.getline(input, sizeof(infile8));

You want to use the size of the input as the maximum, not the size of ifstream class (not the size of the stream -- the size of the class in memory).   

    infile8.getline(input, sizeof(input));

It isn't clear what your 'magic numbers' are meant to be either... 5459, 1321, 1320

Comment: those numbers are the size of the files I am getting. The new file (input) is 5459 chars long for each line. The information I need (output) is 1321 chars long, and of course arrays start at 0 so the final place of output array is 1320.

Comment: In addition to not reading the whole line (for the reason above) you've got an issue with the EOF(potentially based on the solution you got 'duplicated' to).